# Resteasy 3.5.0.Final on App Engine standard env - NoSuchFieldError SERVER_SENT_EVENTS_TYPE

Tags: java, rest, google-app-engine, resteasy

I have a pretty basic Java8 application using Resteasy **3.1.4.Final** deployed in App Engine standard env.

But when I upgrade Resteasy to **3.5.0.Final**;

- All good in my local env
- I get the following Stacktrace when deployed:

> Uncaught exception from servlet
>   java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: SERVER_SENT_EVENTS_TYPE
>       at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethodInvoker.isSseResourceMethod(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:162)
>       at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethodInvoker.(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:147)
>       at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethodRegistry.processMethod(ResourceMethodRegistry.java:345)
>       at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethodRegistry.register(ResourceMethodRegistry.java:272)
>       at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethodRegistry.addResourceFactory(ResourceMethodRegistry.java:223)
>       at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethodRegistry.addResourceFactory(ResourceMethodRegistry.java:195)
>       at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethodRegistry.addResourceFactory(ResourceMethodRegistry.java:181)
>       at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethodRegistry.addResourceFactory(ResourceMethodRegistry.java:158)
>       at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethodRegistry.addPerRequestResource(ResourceMethodRegistry.java:77)
>       at org.jboss.resteasy.spi.ResteasyDeployment.registration(ResteasyDeployment.java:496)
>       at org.jboss.resteasy.spi.ResteasyDeployment.startInternal(ResteasyDeployment.java:279)
>       at org.jboss.resteasy.spi.ResteasyDeployment.start(ResteasyDeployment.java:86)
>       at org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.ServletContainerDispatcher.init(ServletContainerDispatcher.java:119)
>       at org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.HttpServletDispatcher.init(HttpServletDispatcher.java:36)
>       at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.initServlet(ServletHolder.java:643)
>       at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.initialize(ServletHolder.java:422)
>       at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.initialize(ServletHandler.java:892)
>       at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler.startContext(ServletContextHandler.java:349)
>       at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startWebapp(WebAppContext.java:1406)
>       at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startContext(WebAppContext.java:1368)
>       at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doStart(ContextHandler.java:778)
>       at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler.doStart(ServletContextHandler.java:262)
>       at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.doStart(WebAppContext.java:522)
>       at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68)
>       at com.google.apphosting.runtime.jetty9.AppVersionHandlerMap.createHandler(AppVersionHandlerMap.java:244)
>       at com.google.apphosting.runtime.jetty9.AppVersionHandlerMap.getHandler(AppVersionHandlerMap.java:182)
>       at com.google.apphosting.runtime.jetty9.JettyServletEngineAdapter.serviceRequest(JettyServletEngineAdapter.java:97)
>       at com.google.apphosting.runtime.JavaRuntime$RequestRunnable.dispatchServletRequest(JavaRuntime.java:680)
>       at com.google.apphosting.runtime.JavaRuntime$RequestRunnable.dispatchRequest(JavaRuntime.java:642)
>       at com.google.apphosting.runtime.JavaRuntime$RequestRunnable.run(JavaRuntime.java:612)
>       at com.google.apphosting.runtime.JavaRuntime$NullSandboxRequestRunnable.run(JavaRuntime.java:806)
>       at com.google.apphosting.runtime.ThreadGroupPool$PoolEntry.run(ThreadGroupPool.java:274)
>       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

So it's seems to be environment related.
Any clue to solve it?

Thanks

Comment: It's very hard to give you a possible answer in this way.

Maybe you can also update the post with your POM file?

Comment: Thanks @Ggrimaldo, it was effectively a dependency issue.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm posting @NicoNes's answer I received in [Github](https://github.com/resteasy/Resteasy/commit/4410a2642b122443354ded0fac8c21c9cd04882d#commitcomment-28895562)

> Hi @freddyboucher I don't think that this commit is responsible of the
>   NoSuchFieldError you are dealing with. Resteasy 3.1.4.Final is an
>   implementation of the JAX-RS-API 2.0.1 spec whereas 3.5.1.Final is an
>   impl of the JAX-RS-API 2.1 spec. And the missing field you are talking
>   about is coming from the javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType in JAX-RS-API 2.1.
>   So can you please be sure that your runtime execution does not embed
>   the wrong version o the JAX-RS-API ?
>
> Let me know.
>
> -Nicolas

And he was right, I had in my pom.xml:

```
  <dependencyManagement>
      <dependencies>
        <dependency>
          <groupId>javax.ws.rs</groupId>
          <artifactId>javax.ws.rs-api</artifactId>
          <version>2.0.1</version>
        </dependency>
      </dependencies>
  </dependencyManagement>
```

Upgrading to 2.1, fixed my issue!

Comment: Same problem, thank you.  In my case, this reference was being brought in by com.github.docker-java:docker-java v 3.0.13.  Had to update to 3.1.5 to bring in javax.ws.rs-api:2.1 via transitive dependency.

Answer (score 4):

I had the same problem.

I have solved it by deleting org.jboss.resteasy.jaxrs-api.3.0.12.Final from my pom file.

Hope that will solve your problem.

Comment: I don't have any dependency on **org.jboss.resteasy.jaxrs-api**
I also tried with latest Resteasy 3.5.1.Final but same Exception.
Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 3):

I got same error, solved it by excluding the jar in pom.xml

```
<dependencies>
          <dependency>
          [...]
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>javax.ws.rs</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jsr311-api</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
  </dependency>
        </dependencies>
```

Answer (score 0):

I hade the same problem.
I guess any dependency leads probably to a wrong version of javax.ws.rs-api.. I not figured out which exact dependency it was. But just after adding:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.ws.rs</groupId>
    <artifactId>javax.ws.rs-api</artifactId>
    <version>2.1</version>
</dependency>
```

to my pom.xml the problem was solved. No remove of any other dependency was needed