# Resteasy 3.6.3.Final on NoSuchFieldError SERVER_SENT_EVENTS_TYPE

Tags: java, spring-boot

I'm trying to run a spring boot application with Java 1.8 with following dependency, throwing below error.

#### POM.xml

```
 <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.jboss.resteasy/resteasy-jaxrs -->
    <dependency>
     <groupId>org.jboss.resteasy</groupId>
     <artifactId>resteasy-jaxrs</artifactId>
      <version>3.6.3.Final</version>
       </dependency>
    <dependency>
    <groupId>org.jboss.resteasy</groupId>
    <artifactId>resteasy-jaxb-provider</artifactId>
    <version>3.6.3.Final</version>
   </dependency>
   <dependency>      
    <groupId>org.jboss.resteasy</groupId>
    <artifactId>jaxrs-api</artifactId>
     <version>3.0.12.Final</version>
    </dependency>
 client has same version

Error : 
java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: SERVER_SENT_EVENTS_TYPE at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethodInvoker.isSseResourceMethod(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:162) [resteasy-jaxrs-3.6.3.Final.jar:3.6.3.Final]
```

The error is similar to this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49871007/resteasy-3-5-0-final-on-app-engine-standard-env-nosuchfielderror-server-sent-e/55252500#55252500). How do I solve this problem?

Comment: That similar post doesn't resolve your issue?

Comment: No it didn’t resolve it for me any other suggestions

Answer (score 1):

give it a try

change the version of jaxrs-api from 3.0.12.Final to 3.0.10.Final

```
<dependency>      
    <groupId>org.jboss.resteasy</groupId>
    <artifactId>jaxrs-api</artifactId>
     <version>3.0.10.Final</version>
 </dependency>
```